# QT Multi Language support?

Tags: qt

I want to do multi language support for my QT Application ?

Can Anybody guide me what are the steps involved to achieve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Qt has great documentation.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/linguist-manual.html)

*updated to the current one.

Comment: @Naszts : Using Qt linguist i need t0 give particular text and i need to give its conversion also (suppose English->german).Is there not any inbuilt conversion to particular language..

Comment: @user662285: you put e.g. the english text in the source file, like tr("Cancel"), and the translate it in linguist to e.g. "Abbrechen". "Cancel" should show up automatically in the .ts file if you use lupdate correctly. The translation of course only a human can do. Or what else are you asking for?

Comment: @user662285: You will have a default language in your ui files and source code. (e.g.: English). Qt could collect all of the strings from your app. You translate all of them and generate a new language file, what could be built in your app or in to a dll/so. When your application load this dll, it is possible to change the language. (So your app will support both languages.)

Comment: @Naszta : How to translate all of them ? Manually or is there any automatic transaltaion also ?

Comment: @user662285: manually. ([Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) could help a lot.)

Comment: The link in this answer is possibly broken. The new URL should be http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/linguist-manual.html

Answer (score 5):

Practical advice: `tr()` all your user-facing strings. Get this sorted from the beginning and you can retrofit  multi-language support later when you have time to figure it out.

This goes for control-key sequences in menu labels and everything.